# Open Finder alias

Tags: applescript

I'm relatively new to Applescript, I was hoping someone can help me resolve this one...

I have a script that does a spotlight search and returns the found items as `founditems`. The result will either be a folder or an alias to a folder. I'd like to open the found item and it works if the result is a folder but I can't figure how to handle an alias. With an alias I get the error incorporated in the code

```
try
    set theapp to default application of (get info for (POSIX file founditems)) as string
    tell application theapp to open (POSIX file founditems as string)
    activate application theapp
on error e
    display dialog "An error has occured trying to open your file:" & return & return & e buttons {"OK"} default button 1
end try
```

I get 10665 error code. My  guess is that incorporating `original path` may resolve the alias issue but I'm not sure how to plug it in... Thanks much

`founditems` is created this way:

```
set input_var to "12345"
set spotlightquery to "\"kMDItemFinderComment == '" & input_var & "'\""
set thefolders to {POSIX file "/Volumes/RAIDvolume"}


set founditems to {}
repeat with i in thefolders
    set thepath to quoted form of POSIX path of i
    if exists thepath then
        set command to "mdfind -onlyin " & thepath & " " & spotlightquery
        set founditems to founditems & (paragraphs of (do shell script command))
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Not sure if I get your question right, but if you tell the Finder to open the file, it will always opened by the default application. This works for files, aliases and folders.

Comment: That was my assumption as well but as I stated only folders open correctly. Aliases return the error. My guess is that I have to fish out the "Original" from the alias (it shows it when you hit Get Info on the alias). I'm just not sure how to approach that

Comment: Your question is confusing because "founditems" sounds plural to me. It's not founditem for example which would mean 1 item. Because it's plural I would guess that you actually have a list of items. Maybe the list only contains 1 item but it's still a list. If I'm correct then it doesn't make sense when you try to get "POSIX file" of a list. This could be causing all your troubles. Please show how you generate founditems with a spotlight search, then we can help you better.

Comment: ...I've noticed that the code for `founditems` actually returns a list so I tried to use `first item of founditems`but that didn't do any good.. I edited my question to include the part of the code that determines what `founditems` is. Maybe that's where the problem lies. Thanks regulus, looks like we're thinking of the same thing at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was a list because you used "paragraphs of" and I can see now that founditems is a list of posix paths. As such the following will open it with the default application regardless if the path is to a file, folder or alias.

```
set founditems to {"/Users/hmcshane/Desktop/aaa alias"}
set macPath to POSIX file (item 1 of founditems)
tell application "Finder" to open macPath
```